# Calculate area from binary image

Tags: r, r-raster, spatstat

Ahead, I'm not able to provide a minimum working example since I don't know how.
I have an binary mask in an owin. Basically, my data contains five clumped dots of different size. I try to get their area.

As far as I know, the great spatstat package has no function for this.

First, I convert the owin to an raster layer with `raster_mask <- raster(as.im(dd))`.
After that, I detect the clumps as follows:

```
library(igraph)
clusters <- clump(raster_mask)
```

Now I can plot `clusters` with each of the five clusters in its own colour.
And as far as I understand the function `area(clusters)` should provide me with their area, but instead I receive an warning

> This function is only useful for Raster* objects with a longitude/latitude coordinates

For control, I use `crs(clusters)` and see an NA. So I set crs with

```
crs(clusters) <- "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
```

Now I have an CRS, but receive the same warning. My data at this points looks as follows:

```
> print(areas)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 135, 129, 17415  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.9790567, 1.224028  (x, y)
extent     : 490715.5, 490841.8, 5429337, 5429502  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1.198393, 1.198393  (min, max)
```

So I try to change the CSR to longlat.
Before I search for the clumps, using this code and receiving an error.

```
> crs(raster_mask) <- "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
> raster_mask <- projectExtent(raster_mask, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
> plot(raster_mask)
Error in .plotraster2(x, col = col, maxpixels = maxpixels, add = add,  : 
  no values associated with this RasterLayer
```

I might be completely wrong. If someone has an idea how to provide a minimal working example I would be glad to provide it. I hope someone could help me to receive areas from an binary image mask. Any help for orientation is welcome!

Thank you ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know, the great spatstat package has no function for this.

In `spatstat` you can use the function `connected` to identify the connected components.

If `dd` is your original binary mask (object of class `"owin"`), then
`P <- connected(dd)` returns a pixel image `P` with categorical values. Each categorical value corresponds to a connected component. A plot of this image, `plot(P)`, would show a coloured version of the original data, with each connected component filled with a different colour.

You can calculate the areas of each connected component from this. A neat way is to treat the connected components as the tiles in a tessellation.
Example:

```
library(spatstat)
## create example data
dd <- dilation(redwood, 0.5, polygonal=FALSE)
## find connected components
P <- connected(dd)
## convert to a tessellation
B <- tess(image=P)
## compute area of each tile
answer <- tile.areas(B)
```

Comment: Mr Baddeley, thank you very much! It fits like a glove and I need no other package. For large clusters with frayed edges: Is it possible to group very close but isolated pixels together with a larger cluster (or a group of single pixels)? Like you show in your book with `redcon <- connected(redwoodfull, 0.1)`. For this ppp-data `R` can be set, but not for my `owin`-mask. It is feasible with `P <- connected(dd, eps=3)`, but just as a workaround, since this affects the total area of the clusters.